# connecting Eclipse to mysql mac os x jdbc driver

Tags: java, mysql, macos, odbc

I am trying to run this code below while learning the java sql stuff, however, i have created the database and tried it from the terminal its fine.

1-I get this error

```
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sql://localhost/books
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:602)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at Displayauthors.main(Displayauthors.java:20)
```

2-I downloaded "odbc manager" and i don't know why and what to do with it or if it has any relation to what am doing here?

3-I have downloaded Connector/ODBC and Connector/J. I went to JRE reference library and added "mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin.jar" and tried the .tar.gz the multi-platform version. I don't know exactly i kept trying anything and didn't work.

4-I tried to go to database prospective from eclipse and add new connection MYSQL and include the .jar and stuff and still nothing changed.

5-tried to include the class.forName..... and nothing too.

CAN YOU PLEASE PLEASE, HELP ME UNDERSTAND THIS PROCESS OR GUIDE ME TO A CLEAR EXAMPLE ON SETTING THIS UP, I DO UNDERSTAND THE CODE BUT THE ENVIRONMENT SET UP IS GIVING ME HARD TIME.

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Displayauthors {

static final String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:sql://localhost/books";

public static void main(String args[]){

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultset = null;

    try{
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DATABASE_URL, "deitel", "deitel");
        statement = connection.createStatement();

        resultset=statement.executeQuery("SELECT AuthorID,FirstName,LastName FROM Authors");

        ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultset.getMetaData();

        int numberofcolumns = metadata.getColumnCount();
        System.out.println("Authors table");

        for(int i=1;i<=numberofcolumns;i++){
            System.out.printf("%-8s\t", metadata.getColumnName(i));
            System.out.println();

        }
    }
    catch(SQLException sqlexception){
        sqlexception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the correct uri for a mysql database

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname
```

Comment: thanks in advance but well, my database name is books so that's what I thought. However, tried dbname and still got the exact same error :((

Comment: I can imagine you can change 'dbname' what stands for 'database name' to something sensible like 'books' in your case

Comment: so is there something different between mine and what you suggested ? maybe there's something i don't see

Comment: oh my bad !!!! let me try that !! maybe i need glasses, my last question had the problem of a small/cap letter problem... thanks again  and sorry for missing the point earlier..unfortunately i can't vote yet too